# local storage gets cleared when the application is force closed

Tags: html, mobile, cordova, local-storage

I have developed a mobile web application(html5, jquery, css) packaging PhoneGap in which a encrypted id (after first login) is stored in local storage for authentication when, the user logs in the encrypted id is sent to server and hence he is authenticated. This local storage works fine when I go out of the application and come again, but when I force close the application the local storage gets cleared...and the login is need to be done again...

How can I make the local storage presist even if the application is force closed?

Comment: That doesn't happen for me on an Android Galaxy devive. On what devices have you checked?

Comment: Could you show the code that you're referring to.

Comment: SHANK : I'm testing it in Samsung galaxy tab...when i come to home screen and see the recent apps...close it and re-open..I see local storage gets cleared, so hence my app initiates the login screen again

Comment: Ken: if(window.localstorage.getitem("encrypted id"))               load home page();                                                       else                                                                 load login();//javascript code on $(window).load